# C++ 64bit issue

Tags: c++, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

I have the following code:

```
tmp_data = simulated_data[index_data];
unsigned char *dem_content_buff;
dem_content_buff = new unsigned char [dem_content_buff_size];
int tmp_data;
unsigned long long tmp_64_data;

if (!(strcmp(dems[i].GetValType(), "s32")))
{
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos] = tmp_data;
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 1] = tmp_data >> 8;
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 2] = tmp_data >> 16;
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 3] = tmp_data >> 24;      
}

if (!(strcmp(dems[i].GetValType(), "f64")))
{
    tmp_64_data = simulated_data[index_data];
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos] = tmp_64_data;
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 1] = tmp_64_data >> 8;
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 2] = tmp_64_data >> 16;
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 3] = tmp_64_data >> 24;
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 4] = tmp_64_data >> 32;
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 5] = tmp_64_data >> 40;
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 6] = tmp_64_data >> 48;
    dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 7] = tmp_64_data >> 56;
}
```

I am getting some weird memory errors in other places of the application when the second if statement is true and executed.  When I comment out the 2nd if statement, the problem works fine.  So I suspect the way I am performing bitwise operations for 64bit data is incorrect.

Can anyone see anything in this code that needs to be corrected?

Comment: How are you assigning to tmp_data before it is declared? You should probably post your *real* code, as this won't compile.

Comment: What is dem_content_buff_size?

Comment: None of this is going to answer your question, but: 1) you probably want to swap 1st and 4th lines 2) What is the purpose of tmp_64_data? 3) should the second "if" be "else if"?

Comment: ..and what is BytFldPos?

Comment: One obvious question: What is dem_content_buff_size?

Comment: Obligatory: use `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect an interaction between `dem_content_buff_size` and `BytFldPos`.  If the following is not true:

```
assert(dem_content_buff_size > (BytFldPos + 7));
```

then you are going to overflow your buffer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine—from what I can see.  It would be a good idea to have `BytFldPos` range checked before executing.

Answer (score 1):

I would check that `dem_content_buff_size` is large enough for the 64-bit numbers and also that `BytFldPos+7` always lies within the array bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Each element of the `dem_content_buff` array is an unsigned char . You're assigning into each such element a `long long`. Is this your intent?

If not, it could lead to data corruption as that conversion will (or can) lose value.